# Why does my code produce a different result on occasion in apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a very strange problem. I load my app, switch to the correct tab and then press the button I need to press. This runs a function and when I first load the page it may only provide part of the correct result. However if I wait a few seconds it produces the correct result in full. Any ideas why this might be happening?

**Additional Information**

The button simply checks through a list of objects returned via ScriptDB. Objects that are valid are displayed and objects that are in-valid are not. If the object appears again in updates the text to display how many have been found in the list (eg: the label would change from "Object A" to "Object A (2)").

It seems to me like it doesn't have the rest of the list somehow as it doesn't always stop at the same object.  It's Very strange and not something I've experienced before. The other features of my app using ScriptDB work completely regardless of how quickly I use them.

Comment: Is the script in the same spread sheet and the database, or are you passing the database to that sheet? How are you querying your search?

Comment: I've figured it out now. I somehow had some erroneous data in the database which was returning a null field. I can only assume that this was from a import that I did last week from a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Rommel Thanks for your reply, really appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out now. I somehow had some erroneous data in the database which was returning a null field. I can only assume that this was from a import that I did last week from a spreadsheet.

*This was copied from my comment to show that it has been resolved.*